# GIN Index implementation

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, fuzzy-search, database-indexes

Generally Trigram Indexes are supposed to store the trigrams of the values in the index value.
I have understood the structure of GIN Index and how they store the values.
One thing I am stuck with is, whether they would store the trigrams of the texts given or the texts themselves.

I've read some articles and they all show gin index storing words with tsvector
[image]

Now If this is the case, GIN index shouldn't be working for searches like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data LIKE '%word%';
```

But it seems to work for such a case too. I have used a database of a million rows where the column I'm searching on is a random text of size 30. I haven't used tsvector since the column is just a single word of size 30.
Example Column Value: bVeADxRVWpCeEHyNLxxfkfVkSAKkKw

But on using gin index on this column using trgm_gin_ops,
The fuzzy search seems to be much much faster. It works well.

But if gin is just storing the words as it is shown in the above image, it should'nt work for %word%. but it does, which leads me to ask the question: are gin indexes simply made up of the text values or the trigrams of the text values ?

My whole question can be simplified into this:
If I create an index a column with values like this 'bVeADxRVWpCeEHyNLxxfkfVkSAKkKw', would gin simply index this value or would it store the trigrams of the values in it's index tree. (bVe, VeA, eAD,...., kKw)

Comment: Since you haven't explained why you think it shouldn't work, how can we explain why your thinking is wrong?

Comment: Your diagram show words (possibly stemmed?) being stored, but trigram indexes store trigrams, not words.

Comment: Yes, It was a diagram I came across on a blog post that explains the working of GIN indexing. It is what got me confused on whether gin indexes store trigrams of the words or the words them selves ( in stemmed version ).

The reason why I think storing the words as it is or a stemmed version, as opposed to storing the trigrams,  wouldn't work with LIKE '%word%' is that, word can be a substring that is in the middle of a string.
searching on the b-tree works by comparing the values. if 'word' is compared to 'xyzwordabc', it's not going to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The G in GIN stands for generalized.  It just works with a list of tokens per tuple-field to be indexed, but what that token actually represents depends on the operator class to define and extract.  The default operator class for tsvector uses stemmed words, the operator class "gin_trgm_ops" (which is for text, but not the default one for text) uses trigrams.  An example based on one will have limited applicability to the other.  To understand it in a generalized way, you need to consider the tokens to just be labels.  One token can point to many rows, and one row can be pointed to by many tokens.  Once you get into what the tokens mean, that is the business of the operator class, not of the GIN machinery itself.

When using gin_trgm_ops, '%word%' breaks down to 'wor' and 'ord', both of which must be present in the index (for the same row) in order for '%word%' to possibly match.  But '**ord**inary **wor**ry' also has both of those trigrams in it, so it would pass the bitmap index scan but then be rejected by the recheck

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This cleared my doubt on the concept.